# Grub prompt after upgrade from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

I am a Linux newbie who has tried to update from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (used for 3 years) to 12.04 LTS on my Dell desktop using update manager.

I thought all was working well, even though my HD partition desktop is small (just 20gb) and commentary stated short disk space.

I am now faced with the `grub>` prompt, what do I do now?

Can I go back to 10.04 or boot via USB?

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot into Ubuntu 12.04 using a live CD & install 'boot-repair'.

You will first need to add the repository using this command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

Then update your index & install boot-repair using

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

Once installed, run the programs "Recommended Repair" option.
This program is nothing short of a lifesaver.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Cage, will do the Live CD option and follow your instructions.  Is there any scope to get back to 10.04 (or a past state) or do I just move forward?  Will my data be safe?

Comment: @John,
If you have upgraded, boot-repair should get you booting into the new 12.04 Ubuntu. To be perfectly honest, I've never went back after an upgrade, so I'm not sure of the procedure if any.
The boot-repair package only deals with GRUB, so your data will be fine.
Returning to a previous version after upgrade may be possible using APT, but that's a whole other question, although there is not better site to ask on! ;)

Comment: Hi Cage, I just tried to boot via a fresh USB drive (loaded 12.04 ISO) and I get a ¨boot error¨ message?  Instructed my PC (which runs Vista and Ubuntu) to boot via removable drive, just get boot error.  Any clues?  I will try to scan this forum and the help guide. Just can´t get access to my PC which is bothering me now.

Comment: Hi Cage, and sorry if I am repeating myself, I have created a bootable USB (12.04) via my Linux netbook (startup disk creator) but no luck in getting a boot from my dual-boot (Vista and Ubuntu) Dell PC, get ¨boot error¨. I reformatted the brand new USB drive and same issue. Should I format differently, or use a different installer? I am stuck - cannot access my PC.  Just want to get access to my Ubuntu stuff esp. data. My work at stake here.  Just want to work through steps to resolve.

Comment: Hi John, I have also had problems booting from USB drive after using startup disk creator. If you have access to another windows based machine you could try using YUMI available freely from [PendriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) I have found it to be quite reliable. If this does not work your PC may have a problem booting from the USB bus and you may need to use CD/DVD

Comment: Hi Cage, took your advice with pendrive and yes, can now boot via USB, am just so relieved and can see most of my data, yippee. The only issues are files I had on my 10.04 desktop, browser bookmarks and settings and also Thunderbird mail.  Would love to locate these items - is it easy to do?  I am fine to install 12.04 on my PC (and remove both Vista and 10.04) but should I back up all my data first?  Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Hi Cage, update, I would like to backup my data say to USB but now cannot see most of it, though I presume they are still there. How do I check this?  I note the boot repair info, have installed boot repair via sudo but it asks me to backup data before doing the repair, but how do I do that?  At the moment I can only boot via USB-HDD as the option to boot from HDD (and boot menu) has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to "upgrade" or are you willing to do a clean install? I love clean installing on my systems since it gives me a clean start. you could just save your files onto an external HD, then do a clean install of 12.04. That should get rid of the grub.

Comment: I would like to do this but how can I access my data given am stuck at grub?

Comment: Am booting from a live USB but can see all of my files/data, just hoping they are there, how can find and back-up my data esp. that under 10.04.  Live USB does not seemingly give access to system admin eg Gparted, so assume I need to use terminal.  I have tried sudo fdisk -l and see the disk data inc. dev/sda1 etc but none are labelled Linux or Ubuntu (or Windows for that matter), nothing I can obviously use there.  I just wanted to backup my files and data, then do boot repair and/or install 12.04. Any suggestions?